# Prove $2^n - 1$ is NOT a prime number, when n is NOT a prime number also

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I started with $n = 2k$ , $2^{2k} - 1 = (2^k - 1)(2^k + 1)$, where i go from there...

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

If $n = kl$ shows $n$ is composite, then we can write

$$
2^n - 1 = 2^{kl} - 1 = (2^k)^l - 1^l
$$

But do you know of a way to factor $a^l - b^l$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

$ n $ not prime $ \implies $

$$\exists p,q>1 \;\;:\;\; n=pq\implies$$

$$2^n-1=(2^p)^q-1$$
$$=(2^p-1)(1+2^p+2^{2p}+...+2^{(q-1)p})$$

is not prime.